# invalid std::vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I started writing my own particle effect system for a game I'm working on in C++ and sfml.
In my update method I am removing the particles which life time has expired while iterating the vector.
I thought I was careful not to invalidate the iterator after erasing elements as you can see at the bottom of the method, but I'm getting the exec_bad_access code=1 or code=2.
the exception always points to the erase(it) line. 
any ideas what might be wrong?

```
void ParticlesNode::updateCurrent(sf::Time dt)
{
   for(particleIterator it = _mParticles.begin(), end = _mParticles.end(); it != end;)
{
    // calculate new color RGBA
    float nr = it->color.r + it->colorDis.r * dt.asSeconds();
    float ng = it->color.g + it->colorDis.g * dt.asSeconds();
    float nb = it->color.b + it->colorDis.b * dt.asSeconds();
    float na = it->color.a + it->colorDis.a * dt.asSeconds();
    it->color = sf::Color{static_cast<Uint8>(nr),static_cast<Uint8>(ng),static_cast<Uint8>(nb),static_cast<Uint8>(na)};

    // new position
    it->pos = sf::Vector2f(it->pos.x + it->vel.x * dt.asSeconds(), it->pos.y + it->vel.y * dt.asSeconds());

    // new velocity by linear accelaration.
    float length = getLength(it->vel);
    float newLength = length + _mPData.accel * dt.asSeconds();
    float radians = cartesianToPolar(it->vel).y;

    it->vel = polarToCartesian(newLength, radians);
    // new velocity by gravity
    // new velocity by radial acceleration.


    // new remaining life time
    it->lifeSpan -= dt.asSeconds();
    if (it->lifeSpan <= 0)
       _mParticles.erase( it );
    else
        ++it;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) the iterator `it` becomes invalid, but it's still used for the next iteration.

You should assign it by the return value of `erase`, which refers to the iterator following the erased element.

```
it = _mParticles.erase( it );
```

And note that not only the iterator at the point for `erase` becomes invalid, all the iterators after that, including `end()` also become invalid. So you need to evaluate `end()` for every iteration, i.e. change the condition of `for` to

```
for(particleIterator it = _mParticles.begin(); it != _mParticles.end();)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it both ways, with assigning and without, still crashes.

Comment: hey, your second suggestion worked, I failed to re-evaluate the end iterator and that was the curlpit. thanks for straightening me out! one thing though, I don't believe it is necessary to assign it = _mParticles.erase(it); it will be there anyways. Thanks again.

Comment: @BennyAbramovici It might work with your current STL library and compiler, but better not rely on it; because the standard explicitly mentions the expected behavior.